How to chmod -R ug+X only for directories
How can I recursively run chmod to only set executable on directories ?
I mistakenly was under the impression that chmod +X only set executable on directories, but as stated in the man page
execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user (X)

it also sets files executable if any of the executable bits is set as demonstrated below
# mkdir directory
# touch file
# chmod 654 directory file 
# ls -ld directory file
drw-r-xr--. 2 user group 4096 Nov 26 09:50 directory
-rw-r-xr--. 1 user group    0 Nov 26 09:50 file
# chmod a+X directory file
# ls -ld directory file
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group 4096 Nov 26 09:50 directory
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 user group    0 Nov 26 09:50 file

I'm looking for a command that results in
# ls -ld directory file
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user group 4096 Nov 26 09:50 directory
-rw-r-xr--. 1 user group    0 Nov 26 09:50 file

correcting the executable on the directory but leaving the file alone

I managed to track down the cause of the weird file permission 654 which makes no sense, executable by the group but not by the owner. It was caused by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65888/setfacl-incorrectly-changes-group-permissions

find -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod ug+X

should do the trick. Please note it will also affect . (current working directory).

so there is no way to do files and directories in one go. ?

That's a 'one go'. Did you mean - by a single program? I don't know.

You asked for execute to be set on the directories.  This answer supplies that.
What did you want to happen to the files?
